# How to Close Floating Menu when clicking anywhere else but the menu? React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was struck while creating a Floating menu in react JS, the task required is to close the floating menu when a click is recorded anywhere outside the menu, the code snippet is as follows

```
class SectionMenu extends Component {

     state = {
        isOpen: false,
                activeSection: '',
                sectionIds: [],
                coordinates: []
    }

     render() {
         const { sections, hideMenu } = this.props;
         const { sectionIds } = this.state;
    
            return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <FloatingMenu
                    id="floating-menu"
                    slideSpeed={10}
                    direction="left"
                    isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
                    spacing={16}
                    style={hideMenu ? {display: "none"} : null}
                >
                    <MainButton
                        iconResting={}
                        iconActive={}
                        onClick={() => this.setState({isOpen: 
                                                               !this.state.isOpen})}
                        size={}
                    />
                    {"Random Code to bring up each menu item"}
                </FloatingMenu>
            </React.Fragment>
        )    
    }

}
```

I am struck on how to create a useRef/useEffect hook function, is there any method to to it done without useRef as well?
if not how do I do it with useRef/useEffect and/or any other hook?

Comment: Add an (invisible) overlay onder your menu. Then `onClick` on that overlay, close the menu.

Comment: You have a **class** component, hooks can *only* be used in **functional** components.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but you can put an `onClick` on the whole body and make sure to put an `event.stopPropagation()` on the Floating menu

Answer (score 0):

Try to refactor your code using functional component:

```js
const SectionMenu = ({ sections, hideMenu }) => {
  const [sectionsIds, setSectionsIds] = useState([]);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // whatever effect
  }, [])

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <FloatingMenu
        id="floating-menu"
        slideSpeed={10}
        direction="left"
        isOpen={isOpen}
        spacing={16}
        style={hideMenu ? {display: "none"} : null}
      >
      <MainButton
        onClick={() => setIsOpen((prev) => !prev)}
      />
      {"Random Code to bring up each menu item"}
      </FloatingMenu>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've ran up into the same issue  and this worked for me . You can change the onClick() as follows

let isClicked=true;

```
const {/*function name here*/} =()=>{
  if(isClicked){
  document.querySelector("{/*classname here*/}").style = "display:block "
  isClicked=false;
  }
  else{
    document.querySelector("{/*classname here*/}").style = "display:none"
    isClicked=true;
  }
  }
```

This will toggle between true and false.